# Catch the “search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP” when cycle through the badly spelled words

Tags: vimscript

Can anyone show me how to catch the last badly spelled word when vim says ...hit BOTTOM? I tried to do it like this:

```
while 1
    try
        " Jump to the next
        silent keepjumps normal! ]s                                                                                
        let counter += 1
    catch /^Vim[^)]\+):E38[45]\D/
        " do some stuff
        break
    endtry
endwhile
```

Cycling through the badly spelled words works (as it seems to me) like cycling through the searched words. Indeed, if I replace `]s` with `n` and then do some search the try-catch works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you disable the wrapping momentarily while the function is executing?

```
function! CountAll() abort
  let ws = &wrapscan
  set nowrapscan
  try
    keepjumps normal! gg
    " FIXME: If the first word is an error, count it
    " - may be with a reverse search? 
    " - Or by testing the syntax highlighting under the cursor
    let nb = 0
    let p = getcurpos()
    while 1
      silent! keepjumps normal! ]s

      let p2 = getcurpos()
      if p == p2
        " echomsg "No more errors"
        break
      endif
      " else, found...
      let p = p2
      let nb += 1
    endwhile
  finally
    let &wrapscan = ws
  endtry
  return nb
endfunction
```

PS: I was hoping that `catch` would be able to recognize the *"no more error"* case. Alas, with `:silent` it just makes Vim blink. We need to track cursor positions.

Comment: thanks, Luc. It seems to me that I've already tried something like this... The problem is that you have to count them one-by-one. As we well know, many if statements (plus setting/getting/moving of the cursor) when cycling slow down the program, and in fact after cycling the first 100 wrong words in the document the benchmarks starts to fail down seriously.

Comment: My goal is to try to move in tens (`silent! keepjumps normal! 10]s`), then maybe to approximate a little, if the document is greater than 1000 lines so go with `50]s`. This will be faster than counting them one-by-one since it runs in C. The dilemma is that you don't know if `10]s` is actually 10 jumps maybe is 9? If is less than 10 the `try-catch` will stop you before making `let nb += 10` so in the `catch` section you know that the last ten words you need to count them one-by-one, and at the same time you know that you will never count progressively more than 9 times, I think...

Comment: Another possible approach could be to transform/filter line parts that exhibit misspellings syntax-hl. I was able to have acceptable performances to filter out comments with my [`lh#syntax#line_filter()`](https://github.com/luchermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/syntax.vim#L297). May be it could be adapted. The important trick for good performances is to loop with `map()`, `filter()` and reduce with `join()`.

Comment: Back to my initial answer, you could remember the n-2 position, and start back from this position to increment with step/2, and again recursively until the step is 1.