# How to get highlighting group set by spell check

Tags: syntax-highlighting

How do I get the highlighting group of a text when the group is defined by the command `:spell`?

For example when a word is misspelled I want to get the highlighting group `SpellBad`.

We have [a question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16110/1841) on this site about how to get the highlighting group of a text in a buffer, the answer recommends to use the following command:

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

and I also have another command using `synstack`:

```
:synstack(line('.'), col('.'))
```

However both of these commands work pretty well for all of the highlighting groups others than the ones defined by `:spell` (i.e. `SpellBad`, `SpellCap`, `SpellRare` and `SpellLocal`).

The only reference of this bug that I can find is [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464844/how-to-get-group-name-of-highlighting-under-cursor-in-vim#comment61632985_9464929). Am I missing something or does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: synstack also doesn't report search highlights or ones created with `:match` or `matchadd*()`

Comment: correct, synstack only uses the defined highlighting groups. matches or highlight searches, or sign highlights or cursorline or spelling highlights cannot be detected that way

Comment: Thank you Mass and Christian for these additional information, but then it means we have no way to detect these highlights? Hasn't it been an issue to someone else before?

Comment: You can use `expand('<cword>')->spellbadword()` to detect whether the word under the cursor is wrongly spelled, and if so, which type of spelling error it is (`bad`, `rare`, `local`, `caps`).  But that doesn't tell you whether the word under the cursor is highlighted, because it depends on the syntax plugin which can specify where spell checking should be done (see `:h spell-syntax`).

Comment: As a workaround, you could use `term_start()` to open the file in another Vim instance in a terminal buffer, then you could use `term_dumpwrite()` to dump the terminal screen in another file.  Finally, you would have to try to parse the screen dump to check whether the first character of the word is followed by some color code corresponding to one of the spelling error highlight group...  For a start, see `:h terminal-dumptest`, and [this Vim test](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/007f9d6ed597bd212acb95be9d0767c97d2a1438/src/testdir/test_spell.vim#L720-L741).

Comment: @user938271 I like your first idea I'll need to do some tests but that sounds like a promising solution! Your second actually made me smile: I really like this creativity :) I think it's a bit too hacky but I like how you think!

Answer (score 1):

I've already discussed a similar problem.

[Catch the “search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP” when cycle through the badly spelled words](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22456/catch-the-search-hit-bottom-continuing-at-top-when-cycle-through-the-badly-sp)

Briefly said, there is not way to get the hi-group for this type of text, because there is always another hi-group for the same text, for example `String`. You can create a workaround using `]s` and `[s` to discover if under the cursor is a badly spelled word. I tried... it's become extremely slow on big documents. If you want to search for badly spelled words on demand, maybe it will work faster. You decide.

Comment: I could be missing something but I don't understand how your linked question is related to mine: I don't see where you discuss how to get the highlighting group of a misspelled word (I'm not interested in using `[s` several time to find a misspelled word, I know that the word is under my cursor and I want to get its highlight). Also I'm not sure about your   "there is always another hi-group for the same text" explanation: if you create a buffer without filetype and write a word in it, I think the word will not have any highlighting. So if it's misspelled it should have only `SpellBad`

Comment: *"I don't see where you discuss how to get the highlighting group of a misspelled word"* read the comments below Luc Hermitte's answer. *"if you create a buffer without filetype and write a word in it, I think the word will not have any highlighting"*. I tried it now again, also I tried it half year ago and this not seems to be true for me. I just see a blank output...

Comment: About the highlighting I'm sorry if I am missing something in the 4 comments that I've read but the only mention of highlighting is Luc saying that he got acceptable performances getting text with a "Comment" highlight group, I still don't understand how it relates to my issue. About the second part we see the same thing: the function to get the highlight group returns nothing even when the word is not misspelled so "there is always another hi-group for the same text, for example String" is not true otherwise the function would return "String", right?

Comment: All I'm trying to explain to you, that Vim behaves differently as you expect it would. When you move using ```]S (like "]s" but only stop at bad words)``` Vim skips tons of words and jumps directly to a misspelled world; this means that you **derivate** it just like when you do math and approach the solution from another angle...

Comment: Ok thank you for your explanation

Comment: a small addition: *the function to get the highlight group returns nothing when the word is not misspelled* because it uses the hi-names defined by your theme, or hi-names defined by Bram Moolenaar hehe )). Let's **derivate** it: run Vim without any config: ```vim -u NONE``` and write something to the buffer. Now let's change the default hi-name color, because it belongs to ```Normal``` hi-name: ```hi! Normal ctermfg=darkblue```. I see it darkblue, so yes there is **always** another hi-group for the text. The function to get the highlight is just an API to Vim core. Do not trust them too much.